# How to define inner subgraphs in graphviz using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, graphviz

## What

Is it possible, with using the [graphivz lib](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html), to write a subgraph inside another?

## I tried

Using this [API](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=cluster#cluster-py) I tried to get to this image graph. It even came from that other question. That is, I know that it is possible, writing with pure language. However, I need to generate this graph automatically using python, for a state machine

Image:

[image]

### Some code that i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `with` clauses. Like this:

```py
from graphviz import Graph

g = Graph('G', filename="example.gv")

with g.subgraph(name="cluster_outside1") as outside1:
    outside1.attr(label="outside 1")

    with outside1.subgraph(name="cluster_inside1") as inside1:
        inside1.attr(label="inside 1")
        inside1.node("a", "a")
        inside1.node("b", "b")
        inside1.edge("a", "b")

    with outside1.subgraph(name="cluster_inside2") as inside2:
        inside2.attr(label="inside 2")
        inside2.node("c", "c")
        inside2.node("d", "d")
        inside2.edge("c", "d")

with g.subgraph(name="cluster_outside2") as outside2:
    outside2.attr(label="outside 2")
    outside2.node("e", "e")
    outside2.node("f", "f")
    outside2.edge("e", "f")

g.view()
```

So, you need to add a `subgraph` calling the `subgraph` method by the parent graph